# how to import pictures from SQLite Data base?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am doing a project on Contacts For this , I need to Import/Store Pictures in SQlite DataBase.From what I have read , I have to convert the picture into a different format (maybe wrong in this assumption) and then store it in the data Base . Can you please tell me how can I do it or can I use a different method to do it?Both would be helpful for me , so that I can learn a bit more.

Thank You,

Comment: Store the picture as a blob.  You can store any format you wish.

Comment: I m sorry , being very new to android, i dont have a clue what blob is ?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about Android, but read the blessed [documentation for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) before you go asking this sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to get the picture from, whether from the internet or from the sdcard. However, I'm assuming that you can get it and convert it into a bitmap.

```
Bitmap bm = (get it from anywhere);
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//the below line is used if you like to scale it down to store it into the database
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, false);
//then put it into a byte array to store it in the database
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, blob);
// method call to database
dbClass.addPicture(blob.toByteArray());
```

Table definition in the database:

```
SQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pictures (id integer primary key autoincrement, pic blob not null ");
```

addPicture method in the database class is as the following

```
public void addPicture(byte[] picture){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("pic", picture);
    db.insert("Pictures ", null, cv);
}
```

I hope that helps